# Flash MovieClipLoader loadClip on port 82

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am writing a server emulator for a flash application (which is a chatroom).  Everything is fine and works on localhost.  However, My host is unable to open my webserver on port 82.  Therefore, the client cannot load peoples thumbnail images in chat.

Is there a way to make MovieClipLoader loadClip to work on port 82? I've tried making it connect like this: loadClip(server + ':82', path) but it doesn't work and still tries to connect to port 80.

Surely there is another way to do this?

Yes, I'm using As3.  Sorry for not specifying.  I guess its time to find a new host!

Comment: Can you specify if you're using actionscript 2 or 3? I'm assuming 2 here but assuming isn't as good as knowing.

Comment: Also, are you saying you have a server application you're running on your localhost which is bound to port 82? Or are you saying you're running something like xampp and testing locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. Do you have an application or some program listening on port 82 on your server? Probably not, in which case there is no hope of loading anything from port 82 since as far as your application, the server that is running and everything else, there is no port 82. (I mean there is, but there isn't. Nothing is bound to it.) That being said, what do you need to accomplish on port 82 that you can't accomplish on port 80?